# Minimax / Minmax optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, approximation

For the complex polynomial $$P_n(z) := 1+z+\frac{z^2}{2} + \sum_{j=3}^n \gamma_j z^j,\quad z \in \mathbb C.$$ I want to solve the following minimax/minmax optimization problem:
$$\min_{\gamma_j} \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)\in \mathbb C} \big \vert  P_n(\lambda \Delta t) \big \vert -1, \quad \Delta t \in \mathbb R_+ \text{ given.}$$
This problem arises from optimizing the stability region of explicit Runge-Kutta methods with $P_n(z)$ being the corresponding stability polynomial. The minimization over $\gamma_j$ is convex due to the fact that the objective is linear in these coefficients. What gives me trouble is that the coefficients have to be determined "for the worst case", thus the maximization over the eigenvalues of the linear RHS operator.

I already took a look at different questions addressing minimax, e.g. [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171531/minimax-optimization-in-mathematica), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137523/numerically-finding-a-minimax-solution) [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40941/l-infty-norm-minimization) but was not able to find something transferable to my problem.

I tried nesting optimization routine calls like

```
ConvexOptimization[NMaximize[{Abs[Pn[omega * deltaT, gamma]] - 1,
 omega <= 0},omega], {}, gamma];
```

but ran into trouble since inside `NMaximize` `gamma`is not realized:

> NMaximize::nnum: The function value 1-Abs[0.607297 -0.522152 Subscript[gamma, 1]] is not a number at {omega} = {-1.82905}.

If I switch from `ConvexOptimization` to `NMinimize` and specify some custom initial values,

```
ip = Table[{i}, {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}];
NMinimize[NMaximize[{Abs[Pn[omega * deltaT, combinedA]] - 1, omega <= 0}, omega],
gamma, Method -> {"Automatic", "InitialPoints" -> ip}
```

the problem persists

> NMaximize::nnum: The function value 1-Abs[0.607297 -0.522152
> Subscript[gamma, 1]] is not a number at {omega} = {-1.82905}.

Setting the optimization variable `gamma[[1]] = 42`prior to calling the optimizer routines gives for both `NMinimize`aswell as `ConvexOptimization` the (not surprising) error

> NMinimize::ivar: 42 is not a valid variable.
>
> ConvexOptimization::nvar: 42 is not a valid variable.

Comment: What is $e$ in $\sum_{j=3}^e \gamma_j z^j$ from your question?

Comment: And what is $\Delta t$ in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you wish to solve, that is the one in which you would not need to enumerate the eigenvalues, may not be that easy to solve.

However, the one you stated is indeed a convex problem, more specifically a second-order cone program, and you can solve it in Mathematica.

Take for example

```
n = 8;
SeedRandom[3];
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
```

and its eigenvalues

```
eigs = List /@ Thread[\[Lambda] -> Eigenvalues[A]] // Chop
```

Now define the polynomial $P_e$

```
Pe[z_, n_] := 1 + z + z^2/2 + Sum[Subscript[\[Gamma], i] z^i, {i, 3, n}]
```

and evaluate $P_e(\lambda \, dT)$ for each eigenvalue

```
dT = 1/10;
pes = Expand[Pe[\[Lambda] dT, n] /. eigs];
```

Next, assuming that the $\gamma$'s are real, then

```
vars = Append[Variables[Pe[1, n]], \[Rho]];
npes = Map[Norm, Transpose[
    Simplify[{(pes + Conjugate[pes])/2, (pes - Conjugate[pes])/(2 I)},
             Element[vars, Reals]] // Chop]];
```

contains the absolute value of each complex entry in `pes` and

```
SecondOrderConeOptimization[\[Rho], Thread[npes < \[Rho]], vars, MaxIterations -> Infinity]
```

produces

> {Subscript[[Gamma], 3] -> -333.118,
> Subscript[[Gamma], 4] -> -3165.22,
> Subscript[[Gamma], 5] -> 12340.3,
> Subscript[[Gamma], 6] -> -258577.,
> Subscript[[Gamma], 7] -> -28418.7,
> Subscript[[Gamma], 8] -> -1512.65, [Rho] -> 0.908534}

which is a solution to the problem you stated because the value of $\rho$ is an upper-bound to $\max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} |P_e(\lambda dT)|$. That is, it solves the equivalent convex problem

$
\min \{ \rho : |P_e(\lambda dT)| \leq \rho \quad \forall \lambda \in \sigma(A) \}
$

The constant offset of $1$ does not affect the optimal solution.

Comment: Great work, thanks a lot! One thing that is currently not working for me is the special case when one of the eigenvalues is purely real. In that case, the optimizer reports that the curvature cannot be determined. Do you immediately see why that is / what a possible remedy could be?

Comment: The nature of the eigenvalues should not affect anything. Can you post the matrix you’re having trouble with?

Comment: So for instance for eigenvalues `{{\[Lambda]->1.44297},{\[Lambda]->-0.702045}}` (but it is really for any set of eigenvalues where one is purely real) I get the error that the curvature of the constraining polynomials cannot be determined.

Comment: Perhaps because in your example above $n = 2$, in which case the solution to the problem is trivial? I do not have any problem if $n \geq 3$.

Comment: I found the issue - I simply glossed over the line `vars = Append[Variables[Pe[1, n]], \[Rho]];` which went for purely real eigenvalues unnoticed.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [existing answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268194/86460), I found a different way how to formulate the optimization problem.

Define the polynomial $P_n(z)$ as before, only with more input arguments

```
Pe[z_, n_, gamma_] := 1 + z + z^2/2 + Sum[gamma[[i]]*z^i, {i, 3, n}]
```

Then for a rule of eigenvalues of `eigs` (see previous answer) list the polynomials:

```
Pnoms[deltaT_, n_, gamma_] := Expand[Pe[\[Lambda] *deltaT, n, gamma] /. eigs];
```

compute their absolute values

```
AbsPnoms[deltaTIn_, n_, gamma_] := Module[{deltaT = deltaTIn}, 
  pnoms = Pnoms[deltaT, n, gamma]; 
  Return[Map[Norm, Transpose[Simplify[{(pnoms + Conjugate[pnoms])/2, 
  (pnoms - Conjugate[pnoms])/(2 I)}, Element[gamma, Reals]] // Chop]]]];
```

Then an equivalent way how to solve the optimization problem is

```
optVars = Array[Indexed[gam, #]&, e-2];
deltaT = 1;
optRule = ConvexOptimization[Max[AbsPnoms[deltaT, n, optVars]], {}, optVars];
```